# How to update autoGroupColumnDef property of ag-Grid after table is initialized

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have an ag-grid table (Enterprise version: 22.1.0) which is grouped using `autoGroupColumnDef` property. The grouping is dependent on the table's data and the data loads on a button click. I need to update the `autoGroupColumnDef` property's field name (`_this.colName` in the below code) after the page is loaded, right before loading the data.

Table's grid options:

```
_this.gridOptions = {
  defaultColDef: {
      sortable: true,
      resizable: true,
      filter: true
  },
  columnDefs: _this.columnDefs,
  rowData: [],
  enableRangeSelection: true,
  autoGroupColumnDef: {
    headerName: "Sector",
    field: _this.colName,
    cellRendererParams: {
      suppressCount: true
    },
    tooltipValueGetter: function(params) {
      return _this.tooltipVal
    }
  },
  suppressAggFuncInHeader: true, 
  enableBrowserTooltips: true
};
```

I update the variable `_this.colName` before setting data to the grid. I have tried the following options and none of them worked for me:

1. `_this.gridOptions.api.refreshClientSideRowModel('group');`
2. `_this.gridOptions.api.refreshCells();`
3. `_this.gridOptions.autoGroupColumnDef.field = 'Column's Name'`

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted ag-grid support and apparently this is a bug and they have it in their backlog with no ETA available for now. A workaround they provided was to use: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/#showRowGroup.

This is not really a good workaround because the grouped columns are separated and makes the page feel cramped. Also there are some look and feel issues that keep popping up (Eg: empty space added before each column that increases with each grouped column. ie second column has 1 cm added before it, third column has 2 cm added before it and so on. I guess this was added to bring the grouped look in the group column but you wouldn't expect this behavior when the columns are separated.)

ag-grid's backlog ID for the ticket: *AG-3359 - Allow the autoGroupColumn to be used in the API calls for columns, at the moment there is no way to dynamically change it after creation. (ie, setColumnDefs …)*

Link to track the progress: https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-pipeline/

Comment: Thanks for the effort you have taken to reach out to ag-grid team to get clarity on this issue.

Comment: was it solved? I can't find the issue in the backlog, however, it still exists in v28.2.1

Answer (score 3):

There is a good workaround for this.  You can set autoGroupColumnDef, then remove and readd all row groupings.  It will redraw the group column with the new name.

```
    gridOptions.autoGroupColumnDef.headerName = 'new_name';
    
    // Get current groupings
    var colstate = gridOptions.columnApi.getColumnState();
    var colstateclear = gridOptions.columnApi.getColumnState();

    // Clear groupings
    var x = 0, xcount = colstateclear.length;
    while ( x < xcount ) {
        colstateclear[x].rowGroupIndex = null;
        x += 1;
    }
    gridOptions.columnApi.setColumnState(colstateclear);
    
    // Reset groupings  
    gridOptions.columnApi.setColumnState(colstate);
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a straight forward method to update the autoGroupColumnDef object and its properties with **setAutoGroupColumnDef**

```js
this.gridOptions.api.setAutoGroupColumnDef(<ColDef>{
    ...this.gridOptions.autoGroupColumnDef, // preserve the other settings except the ones you need to change
    minWidth: 500
  })
```

if any problems with the spread operator,
do it manually:

```js
this.gridOptions.api.setAutoGroupColumnDef(<ColDef>{
    // ...this.gridOptions.autoGroupColumnDef, // preserve the other settings except the ones you need to change
headerName: this.gridOptions.autoGroupColumnDef.headerName,
    minWidth: 500
  })
```

and one more thing, add this if you have any visual bugs, like: header row gets resized but bellow rows stays the same as previus state, so the refresh of model is required:

`this.gridOptions.api.refreshClientSideRowModel();`

this refresh is not ideal solution, because it refreshes everything, so you will loose expanded levels for example, still no clue how to preserve all settings.
https://angulargrid.com/angular-grid/client-side-model/#refreshing-the-client-side-model

and best solution for now is tu use:

```
this.gridOptions.api.redrawRows();
```

it keeps the rows expanded if are, checkbox selected if is.